# Forces on a catenary cable span

Tags: mechanical-engineering, force-measurement

This relates to an unusual action on a catenary cable span and is not covered by the many available calculators or standard formulas. I'll add a diagram 'tomorrow' if attention warrants. (0400 now - sleep calls).

I am seeking to determine the forces on a catenary cable span when a short length is added to the original cable and the anchor point is moved slightly, both instantaneously.

- Here length change is short relative to the original length and anchor point movement is small relative to overall length of span.

This situation occurs when the attachment at one end of the cable fails and the cable starts to fall until a safety wire is tensioned by the falling cable such that a new slightly longer span results. The static tension on the old and new span can be easily calculated. The dynamic transitional forces are harder.

I am interested in the dynamic forces which will occur as the new longer catenary cable is tensioned. I initially assume that the "safety cable" attaches at the end of the original cable, but in real life it would probably attach a 'small' distance down the original span.

The mass per length, length and material of the main and added material are known.
I assume that both cables are effectively inextensible, but the  added cable could be 'stretchable' if it made a significant difference in forces.

I'll be pleased in the unlikely event that a calculator already exists for this situation. Failing that, any suggestions on how to model this situation are welcomed.

Comment: I am fairly confident that there is no simple (or even complicated closed form) calculation for this. My inclination would be to use MBD software to simulate this. This is an example http://oss.jishulink.com/caenet/forums/upload/2012/09/27/110/42024053102992.pdf You will find that additional compliance is helpful. A major effect would be whipping of the primary cable, which will affect the effective stiffness of the cable. If you want to pursue classical solutions then the Holy Grail is Summary of Information and Data on Cable Dynamics, NAMC
Report No. M5933, 1955. by Dr Ringleb

Comment: @GregLocock Thanks. I've had several non calculation / modelling based suggestions. Your link has introduced me to ADAMS and MBD software in general. This looks potentially very appropriate. || Now I need to find an affordable (free is always good :-) ). MDB tool that has suitable capability and a learning curve that I can tolerate. So much to know :-) .

Comment: Free MBD software exists. Project Chrono is one, Modellica/Dymola is another. Now, I used to have access to ADAMS and so am very familiar with the general concepts, but have been unable to make any headway with either. The Chrono user forums seem less noob hostile than the other lot, who I gave up on a long time ago.Your project is what my old manager would have called a science project, which he hated. It'll need  a ton of testing work to verify your model. https://projectchrono.org

Comment: @GregLocock Thanks.Much found with webs searches on [Modelica/Dymola](https://www.google.com/search?q=Modellica%2FDymola&sca_esv=592113278&sxsrf=AM9HkKkEoOlTVUfcJTFnJJhs49Gz6fB65w%3A1702971568498&ei=sEiBZbeGHsC00-kPqM2RgAM&ved=0ahUKEwi3npy7_5qDAxVA2jQHHahmBDAQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=Modellica%2FDymola&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEE1vZGVsbGljYS9EeW1vbGEyBxAAGIAEGA0yBhAAGB4YDTIIEAAYCBgeGA0yCBAAGAgYHhgNMggQABgIGB4YDTIIEAAYCBgeGA0yChAAGAgYHhgNGA8yChAAGAgYHhgNGA8yChAAGAgYHhgNGA8yCBAAGAgYHhgNSMmqN1DamDdY2pg3cAJ4AJABAJgB4gGgAeIBqgEDMi0xuAEDyAEA-AEB4gMEGAEgQYgGAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) ad ...

Comment: ... [Project Chrono](https://www.google.com/search?q=Project+Chrono&oq=Project+Chrono+&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiABDIGCAIQRRg7MgcIAxAAGIAEMgcIBBAAGIAEMgcIBRAAGIAEMgcIBhAAGIAEMgcIBxAAGIAEMgcICBAAGIAEMgcICRAAGIAE0gEIMzk1OWowajSoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) || This "science project" is  'real project'. I thought of modelling it as a DIY finite element task (which I may still try) but the concepts and links provided are most useful.

Comment: It is a finite element problem, and I suspect in 2D it might be possible to handroll a matlab/octave script,  but it is off the deep end for me. Of course if you can handle whacky then Algodoo might even work.

Comment: @GregLocock  I'm a professional electrical engineer. This is well outside my comfort zone BUT I have decades of needing to interface with non electrical things that impinge on my electrical/electronic world.  || I've been thinking about it in 2D and it may work well enough - even with a DIY coded FE solution. As per your old manager - testing the model is acceptable. A purely mechanical test MAY suffice - but it would need to be a small scale model.

Comment: @GregLocock You seem to be the only one answering. Your input has been extremely useful. The above material should be able to be made into an answer that would be useful to others long term without too much effort. I'd happily accept an answer containing the above. Of extra value for others is knowing about both MBD software in general and the free offerings in general. One of the freebies is good enough that the US Army have put in useful $ to improve it for work with their vehicle modelling, and NASA are using it for their latest Lunar Rover design.